# in mvc [required]attribute errormessages for string variable alone im getting customerrormessges but not for bool ,datetime,int

Tags: asp.net-mvc

My code is like

```
public class user
{

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "please enter username")]
    public string username { get; set; }
```

for this string property im getting error message properly. but...

```
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "please enter dateof birth")]
    public DateTime DOB { get; set; }
```

for this im getting default model state validator message im getting like:

> "Required property 'DateTime' not found in JSON. Path '', line 5, position 2".

I want here "please enter dateof birth" .message im unable to get this ..for bool or datetime or int im unble to get can someone help on this .thanks in advance

Comment: Assuming your using `@Html.CheckBoxFor()` how would you expect to get a validation error for `bool` (both `true` and `false` are valid). As for the the `DateTime` property - show the relevant code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am going to take a guess that you are trying to assign `null` to `DOB`. `DateTime` is not nullable, you can allow nulls by changing it as follows:

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "please enter dateof birth")]
public DateTime? DOB { get; set; }
```

This also works for `int?` and `bool?` too